# pkl file create on centos 9 stream , but can't load in mac os 14.2

Tags: python, pickle

```
with open(f'{path}','wb') as file:

    pk.dump(object,file,protocol=HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

```
with open(loadfile,'rb') as file:

    o=pk.load(file)
  
    return  o
```

`\_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\\x00'.`

I run such code in Centos 9 stream, got a pkl file ， load in Mac os 14.2
conda env is same,python version is same